# Why JacksonJsonProvider ignores MediaType's parameters?

Tags: java, json, jboss, jackson, resteasy

Im currently working on Version2 of some RESTful API and to maintain compatibility with Version1 I wanted to add the version as media type parameter to all requests/responses.

Version1: Accept: application/json, application/json;application&version=1.0

Version2: Accept: application/json;application&version=2.0

In Version1 all timestamps were serialized as time in ms since 1970, Version2, however, will use ISO-8601.

My idea was to extend the JacksonJsonProvider for the media type application/json;application&version=2.0:

```
@Provider
@Produces("application/json;application&version=2.0")
public class MyProvider extends JacksonJsonProvider {
    public MyProvider() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
        mapper.setDateFormat(sdf);
        setMapper(mapper);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.err.println("\n\n*** MyProvider#isWriteable: mediaType:" + mediaType.toString() + "\n with parameters: " + mediaType.getParameters());
        return true;
    }

}
```

and the test resource:

```
@Path("/test")
public class TestResource {
    @GET
    @Produces("application/json;application&version=2.0")
    public Response test( @Context HttpServletRequest request ) {
        Vehicle v = new Vehicle();
        return Response.ok(v).build();
    }
}
```

The problem is, that the default JacksonJsonProvider is used without taking care of the media type's parameters. If I change all media types to e.g. `@Produces("application/something")`, MyProvider is called and the dates within the Vehicle object get serialized according to the specified DateFormat.

My question is: how can I change the greedy behaviour of the default JacksonJsonProvider so that media type's parameters are considered?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A common method of changing/upgrading a ReSTful API is to create new endpoints for the new implementations.

I.e. if you have

```
@Path("/rest/api/issue")
```

and you would like to add a different implementation of the same endpoint you would add a new piece to the path

```
@Path("/rest/api/{version}/issue")
```

Where {version} is whatever version of the api you're choosing.

Atlassian's JIRA API does things in this way: https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/jira/5.0.html

Also, using the built-in constants for media types is good form:

```
 @GET
 @Path("/rest/api/2/issue")
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I watched [REST+JSON API Design - Best Practices for Developers](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=hdSrT4yjS1g#t=1947) by Stormpath and they suggest to use the header's metadata to distinguish between the API Versions.
I never thought this approach would be so hard to realize... Creating a new endpoint is ok but in my opinion hiding the information what API version to use in the HTTP header as metadata is a neat solution.